# How do I get foreground and background colors of a face?

Tags: faces, face-attributes

I would like to print face color attribute, below code just print the name. how to print the foreground color and background color?

```
(print 'font-lock-function-name-face)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the list of face attributes at [`face-attribute-name-alist`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/emacs.git/tree/lisp/faces.el?h=6b560992681a1588ed4ed0c6b103021f8b13e056#n1234)

```lisp
(defun dump-face-attributes (face &rest props)
  (cl-loop for prop in (or props
               (sort (mapcar #'car face-attribute-name-alist)
                 (lambda (s1 s2)
                   (string< (symbol-name s1) (symbol-name s2)))))
       for val = (face-attribute face prop nil t)
       unless (eq val 'unspecified)
       append (list prop val)))

(defun get-face-attribute (face prop)
  (plist-get (dump-face-attributes face prop) prop))
```

and you use it like this

```lisp
(get-face-attribute 'font-lock-function-name-face :foreground)
```

```lisp
(get-face-attribute 'font-lock-function-name-face :background)
```

```lisp
(dump-face-attributes 'org-code)
```

Here is a sample session in `M-x ielm` using above functions

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) or press C-h m for help.
ELISP> (get-face-attribute 'font-lock-function-name-face :foreground)
"#4949d7"
ELISP> (get-face-attribute 'font-lock-function-name-face :background)
nil
ELISP> (dump-face-attributes 'org-code)
(:foreground "grey50" :inherit shadow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `face-background/foreground` for that.
For example

```lisp
(face-foreground font-lock-function-name-face)
```

(remember to also read `face-foreground` its docstring)